# How to match br tag in XPath text() function

Tags: ruby, xpath

I have a following element.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
driver.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[14]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font").text
=> "unique\ntext"
```

But I don't want to rely on unstable table layout, so I decided to use `text()` function in xpath like:

```
driver.xpath("//font[text()='unique\ntext']")
=> nil
```

But as you see, I couldn't find the element by the `text()` function. The original text is `unique<br>text`.

How can I match the `<br>` tag by using XPath?

There is no `id` or `name` attributes that I can use.

Comment: I don't think you can. `<br>` is a node, not contents of a text element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text()` test selects any text nodes. In this example there are *two* such nodes, before and after the `<br>`. It is not the same as the `text` method or the string value of the parent node.

One way of selecting what you want could be like this:

```
driver.xpath("//font[ . ='unique\ntext']")
```

You might need to add extra newlines before or after the text. Note that this relies on Ruby doing the conversion of `\n` into an actual newline character before passing the query to the XPath processor, so you need to be careful about getting your quotes right. This compares the *string-value* of the node, which for an [element is the concatenation of all the descendent text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes), which is what you want.

A better solution might be to use the [`normalize-space()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) here (as long as the unique aspect of the text doesn’t depend on the newlines).

Try:

```
driver.xpath("//font[normalize-space()='unique text']")
```

Note that all leading and trailing whitespace in the target text has been removed, and any internal whitespace is changed to a single space character.

Comment: I didn't know  `normalize-space()` function. Thanks!